# Async | Can not get my async promise to function

Tags: javascript, express, promise, async-await

I'm currently writing a login server function and I cannot figure out why the posmise that I'm making isnt being called

Im using mongodb with mongoose as the backend that is being connected to using the User.findOne which works. I cannot figure out why the bottom console.log for Test and test2 never get fired.

I'm quite new to the promise and async and I can't figure out what im missing

```
class HandlerGenerator {
  login (req, res) {
      console.log('debguh1')
      let username = req.body.username;
      let password = req.body.password;
      let checkUsername = "";
      let checkPassword = "";

      var lData = {
          username: req.body.username,
          password: req.body.password
        };

      var myPromise = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          console.log('db2')
          User.findOne(lData , function(err, userLogin){
              if(err){
                console.log(err);
                return
              }
              console.log(userLogin)
              checkUsername = userLogin.username;
              checkPassword = userLogin.password;

            });
          });
        };

      var callMyPromise = async () => {
          var result = await (myPromise());
          // call code here
          console.log("Test1")
          resolve(result);
          //return result
        };

      callMyPromise().then(function(result) {
        console.log('Test2')
          res.json(result);
          });

  }
}
```

Comment: comment the resolve, uncomment the return. but also note that callMyPromise is redundant, you could just call myPromise instead.

Comment: You never resolve your first promise. You need to resolve somewhere inside the `User.findOne()` callback.

Comment: What's the point of declaring all these functions that you call only once?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using mongoose for your queries, `.exec()` is returning a promise.
By making your login method async you can now await the response. But do make sure to wrap an await in a try catch block or HOF, to handle errors / or not found users.

```js
class HandlerGenerator {
  async login(req, res) {
    let { username, password } = req.body;
    let checkUsername = "";
    let checkPassword = "";

    var lData = {
      username
      password
    };

    try {
      const userData = await User.findOne(lData).exec();
      res.json(userData);
    } catch (e) {
      // do some error handling in here
    }
  }
}
```